# X11 error in MAC OS X

Tags: macos, mac, xorg, r, x11-forwarding

When I try to run x11 on my mac in R i get the following error:

> x11()
>   Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  : 
>     unable to start device X11
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In x11() : unable to open connection to X11 display ''

can someone tell me how to get x11 working? I have OS X version 10.9.5

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and installing R separately from Rstudio fixed it. You can download it from [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/) and verify x11 is working using x11()